# Best practice tu run code only once and only when you open an app. Swift 4, Xcode 8.

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, global-variables

I am trying to run a function only once only when the app is opened.

**Background**

I have a stored array (we'll call it storedArray) in user defaults that takes its value from an array that can be modified by the user (userArray).

**Problem1:** Every time I open the app, storedArray has the values of the previous sessions and of course userArray is empty again. So when the storedArray takes values again from the userArray the storedArray looses its previous values.

**Solution to problem1:** When you open the app the userArray gets filled with the values of the storedArray (from the previous session).

No problem there. Now:

**Problem 2:**This must happen only once every time the app is opened, otherwise the userArray will start appending the storedArray values many times with repeated values. I figured out solutions 1 and 2, number 3 I tried to follow advice from other posts but failed to understand it and implement it.

**Possible Solution 1:** Declare a global variable

```
Struct globalVariables{
static var x = 0
}
```

Create an if statement so that the desired code runs only if globalVariables.x == 0

```
if globalVariables.x == 0 { 
//code to append values from storedArray to userArray goes here
//Then give a new value to globalVariables.x so that the if never gets accessed again
globalVariables.x == 1
}
```

This works but I don't know if it as a good practice.

**Possible Solution 2:** Put the code to be run only once inside the application function in the AppDelegate file.

This functions looks like this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
//code to append values from storedArray to userArray goes here
```

}

Again this works but I don't know if it is a good practice.

**Possible Solution 3:** If I understood correctly, the suggested solution in other posts was to use a singleton. I could never really make this work, (or properly understood what a singleton is).

I made a new .swift file with the following code:

```
struct Service {

static let sharedInstance = Service(

func getStoredInfo () {

          //code to append values from storedArray to userArray goes here
    }
  }
}
```

Then call this function in a viewDidLoad with:

```
Service.sharedInstance.getStoredInfo()
```

The function still gets called every time the viewDidLoad runs. If the singleton can really help me with this I am totally missing something very basic about what a singleton is and how to implement it. Totally.

Are solutions 1 and 2 good practices? Maybe there are other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t understand why you have problem 2. When you launch the app, load `userArray` from defaults. Each time you update `userArray`, also write it back to user defaults.  That is all you need to do. Your problem should seem to come from appending the stored data to `userArray`; don’t do that.  Just replace the contents with the stored array. Even better than all of this is don’t use user defaults as a data store.

Comment: How do you recommend storing data?

Comment: Core Data is one way.

Answer (score 0):

If something need to be done only after launch then 'application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' is definitely the way to go.

Problem : On iOS you don't control when your app is terminated. You need to store how the app was terminated, so you can restore the session or start a fresh one.